# How to make a script command work in both linux & UNIX

Tags: linux, shell-script, historical-unix

As the command `NUMBER=$((${NEW_COUNT}-${OLD_COUNT}))` in a shell script did work in Linux system but not work in UNIX system, how can I make a new command work the same as the above command in UNIX system?

Comment: What shell are you using in this "UNIX" system?

Comment: Type `echo $0` to determine your current shell on Unix.

Comment: What Unix is the other Unix system and what shell are you using there? You have tagged your question with [tag:historical-unix], which indicates a _very old_ implementation, i.e. not a recent version of something like AIX or Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [**`expr`** util](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expr):

```
NUMBER=`expr "${NEW_COUNT}" - "{$OLD_COUNT}"`
```